# Simple for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have this simple for loop but unfortunately I'm unable to run it successfully.

This is what I have:

For Loop

```
 var imagesPerPage = 2

  for (i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
    if (i > imagesPerPage) {
     alert('more');
     }else{
     alert('less');
     }
  }
```

When I run this code `first` If I have **<= 2** then I get `"less"` alert `twice`.
But when I have **> 2** then I get `"less"` alert `twice` and `"more"` alert `once`.

Can anyone say me where am I going wrong?

Comment: see whats returned by response.d.length so that you can figure out how many times for loop is called

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use a simple `if` construct for this?

```
var imagesPerPage = 2

if ( response.d.length > imagesPerPage ) {
  alert('more');
} else {
  alert('less');
}
```

In your code the loop runs always `response.d.length` times. In the first two times the false part of your if fires and results in the two "more" alerted. After that all other runs use the true part of your if-clause and will return "more". In any case all runs are done no matter what you alert.

You can however stop the loop by inserting a `break` command at the point you want to leave the loop. This, however, oftentimes leads to very unclear code and thus should be avoided if possible. (Besides, I doubt, that this would be your desired behavior.)

Comment: @Sirko-First thanks for you'r reply.As I'm trying to make a pagination so trying to make a for loop for that and checking the "i" value and adding some images using that.If I use this way can I do that by incrementing the value.

Comment: @coder I added a paragraph explaining the behavior of your code, maybe that is of some help.

Comment: @Sirko-+1 for the quick reply.I will look into that:)

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need a for loop? I think this should suffice:

```
 if ( response.d.length > imagesPerPage ) 
 {
   alert('more');
 }
 else
 {
   alert('less');
 }
```

Comment: @Mithrandir-+1 for the clarification.